# About DirectShow source filter

Tags: audio, directshow

I have created (C++, Win10, VS2022) a simple source DirectShow filter. It gets audio stream from the external source (file – for testing, network – in future) and produces audio stream on output pin, which I connect to soundspeaker.

In order to do it I have implemented FillBuffer method for the output pin (CSourceStream) of the filter. Media type - MEDIATYPE_Stream/MEDIASUBTYPE_PCM.
Before being connected the pin gets info about media type via SetMediaType (WAVEFORMATEX) and remembers parameters of audio - wBitsPerSample; nSamplesPerSec; nChannels. Audio stream comes from the external source (file or net) to FillBuffer with the parameters - wBitsPerSample; nSamplesPerSec; nChannels. It works fine.

But I need to handle situation, when external source will send audio stream to the filter , with another parameter (for example, old sample had 11025 Hz, and the current = 22050).

Could you help me – which actions and calls should I make in FillBuffer() method if I will receive audio stream with changed wBitsPerSample or nSamplesPerSec or nChannels parameter ?

The fact is that these parameters have already been agreed between my output pin and the input pin of the soundspeaker and I need to change these agreement correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve the implementation and handle

> ## [Dynamic Format Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/dynamic-format-changes)
>
> ...
>
> `QueryAccept` (Downstream) is used when If an output pin proposes a format change to its downstream peer, but only if the new format does not require a larger buffer.

This might be not trivial because baseline DirectShow filters are not required to support dynamic changes. That is, ability to change format is dependent on your actual pipeline and implementation of other filters.

You should also be able to find [SDK helpers](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/blob/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/filters/synth/dynsrc.h#L13), `CDynamicSourceStream` and `CDynamicSource`.

Comment: Roman, thank you for your advice. I will learn mentioned materials.

Comment: Roman, thank you for your advice. I will learn mentioned materials. Additional question is - when FillBuffer() gets know that format must be changed, it can can return S_FALSE (end of stream). My question is - what happened with the graph state in this situation ? It will be stopped and I can catch the graph message about it ? So, after detecting this situation the main program could start the reconnection... Is it possible approach ? (the graph consists of 2 filters - my filter and audio renderer (sound speaker).

Comment: End of stream notifications are unrealted to dynamic format changes. So following the linked article above, your `FillBuffer` would have to, first, "Calls IPin::QueryAccept or IPinConnection::DynamicQueryAccept on the downstream pin, to verify whether the other pin can accept the new media type (see illustration, step A)." and then  "... Then it calls `IMediaSample::SetMediaType` to attach the media type to that sample (C)." When your sample is ready it will have a new media type attached to it, and receiving pin, which already confirmed this media type, will see that the change is finalized.

Comment: Roman, about "End of stream notifications are unrealted to dynamic format changes..." - I have understood it and will try this approach. In my last comment I had in mind another approach - to force filter stopping via end of stream notification and then reconnect filters outside of FillBuffer.

Comment: The thing is that old school filters that do not support dynamic reconnection can't change media type just because of EOS, the need full transition to stopped state. Newer filters capable to reconnect dynamically don't need EOS because they can change media type right away. The problem with stopping is smoothness of the swich, it won't be accurately smooth, if you are okay with this then new media type through stopping is apparently an easier solution.

Comment: Roman, it seems I have dealt with the mentioned filters - QueryAccept returned S_FALSE, DynamicQueryAccept - E_FAIL. I have tested it by changing NChannels parameter , for example. I suppose it will be neccessary to stop my graph and reconnect. The smoothing problems seems to be not very important because of changing format will be rare, ideally - one time when main program and the filter will connect with the external source of audio stream.